# sarcastic vs sarcastically

Tags: adjectives

Where is the difference between these two forms?

> His message was meant sarcastic.
>
> His message was meant sarcastically.

Comment: The first one is not correct grammatical ;)

Comment: @mplungjan Can you add an answer with details when which form has to be applied?

Comment: It is an adverb so it has ly at the end http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sarcastically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one is an *adjective* and the other is an *adverb.* So, the first is not grammatical because you cannot use the adjective form of the word that way. The second is grammatical and uses the correct form of the word, adverb. You can fix the first by removing *meant* from it.

> His message was sarcastic. Or His message was meant to be sarcastic.

I'd not even use the second but I don't say it's not grammatical.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the second one is valid English, and the second isn't.  For the first to make sense it would have to read:

> His message was meant to be sarcastic.

A person or phrase can be *sarcastic*, but whatever they say is said *sarcastically*.  As mplungjan said, "sarcastically" is an adverb, and has to include the "-ly" when used as such.  You can only omit the suffix when using the word as an adjective.  A similar word would be "caustic" which would need the same suffix when used as an adverb.